# How to get the max number and key

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I have has like this

```js
var hash = {};
hash['a'] = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
hash['b'] = ["a", "b", "c"];
hash['k'] = ["q", "b"];

Math.max(Object.keys(hash)
    .map(function(key) {
      return hash[key].length;
    })
  )
```

It returns 5 but, I want to get the hash key `'a'` at the same time.

Is it possible??

Comment: add the desired output, for your problem

Comment: I want to get the key of max length in this case 'a'

Comment: `Object.keys()`/`Object.entries()` + `Array.prototype.reduce()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get the key and the elements behind that key (and their length)

```js
var hash = {
   a: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
  ,b: ["a", "b", "c"]
  ,k: ["q", "b"]
};

var result = Object.entries(hash)
                   .reduce((r, c) => r[1].length > c[1].length ? r : c);
                   
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I am learning about reduce and it works as I expect. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Does this fulfil your requirement?

I have used `sort` instead of `Math.max` here to find the maxima

```js
var hash = {};
hash['a'] = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
hash['b'] = ["a", "b", "c"];
hash['k'] = ["q", "b"];

var result = Object.keys(hash)
    .map(function(key) {
      return {[key]: hash[key].length};
    }).sort(function(a, b){ 
      return a.key > b.key
    })[0]
  
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

i have used this approach for your problem:

```
var hash = {};
hash['a'] = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
hash['b'] = ["a", "b", "c"];
hash['k'] = ["q", "b"];

var largestInfo = {
  key:'',
  length:0
}

 Object.keys(hash).map(function(key) {
    if(hash[key].length > largestInfo.length){
        largestInfo.key = key;
        largestInfo.length = hash[key].length;
    }
    return hash[key].length;
});
console.log(largestInfo);
```